# How do I run Bioblender?

Tags: 12.10

I have downloaded the zip file for linux http://bioblender.eu/DB/BioBlenderv0.6_Linux.zip and extracted its contents, ran `cd` to the extracted directory but then when I ran `./blender` as per the instructions in the text file, **README_LINUX** that I found in the extracted directory, I received the error:

```
./blender: error while loading shared libraries: libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The exact contents of the README_LINUX file are:

```
This setup works for Blender 2.55 on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS "Lucid Lynx", 32 bits.

1. First of all you need to have Python 2.6 or 2.7 installed, together with the matching version of Numpy (Numerical Python). 
You can find them in Ubuntu Sofware Center or install them using Synaptic.

2 You need Pymol installed, you find it in the official Universe repository for Lucid. 
Just enable "Universe" in "Software sources", in the Sofware Center and install Pymol as you did with Python/Numpy.

3 Unpack BioBlender in a suitable folder (your home folder should be ok)


4 Cd to the directory containing BioBlender executable and launch it from the console:

./blender
```

I have blender, python and pymol installed at their latest respective versions available in software centre. I think I have numpy installed, because I know I have [sagemath](http://sagemath.org/) installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-file search libjpeg.so.62` tells you it's provided by:
[image]

So `sudo apt-get install libjpeg62`.